# Importing csv data with --headerline and specific field type in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Here is query I am using:

```
mongoimport -c analyst -d usersight --type csv --columnsHaveTypes --headerline "_id.string(),Dimension.string(),Media.string(),Sentiment.string(),Popularity.string(),Date.date(2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z\),Keywords.string()" --file test.csv
```

If I Specify without **--headerline** ,using **--fields** and removing first row from CSV it works fine.

Here is the sample data:

```
_id,Dimension,Media,Sentiment,Popularity,Date,Keywords

ObjectId(5a1be7b491be4fc23b516649),Twitter,Neutral,,,2015-12-31T18:30:00.000Z,, 

ObjectId(5a1be7b491be4fc23b51664d),Twitter,Neutral,,,2015-12-31T18:30:00.000Z,,
```

Please tell where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The command below will import the csv

```
mongoimport -c analyst -d usersight --columnsHaveTypes --type csv --headerline --file test.csv
```

the data has to be changed to such:

`Dimension.string(),Media.string(),Sentiment.string(),Popularity.string(),Date.date(2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z\),Keywords.string() 
Twitter,Neutral,,,2015-12-31T18:30:00.000Z,,`

Unfortunately, I dont think `--columnsHaveTypes` can be use to import ObjectId

Comment: But, I have to add specific type of field in mongo. If I provide the above command everythng will go as a string type.I want to save date as date type.

Comment: in that case, let me edit my answer to suit your requirement

Comment: the data is abit longer than expected thus the wraparound is breaking the code quote but I think you get the idea. The header line has to be change to include the type

Comment: Is it possible to specify field type while using --headerline??

Comment: query you had provided works fine for me but my requirement is to not manually specify field name using --fields, instead use CSV first row as column name with specific field type.

Comment: Please read my edited answer again. It is exactly what you want. The csv will contain the field and type in the first row. You do not need to specify it in the command line.

Comment: I edit my answer again down to the minimum instruction and re-test that it is working. Hope this helps.